# in_array ignoring first item in array

Tags: php

This one has me stumped. We get a large CSV file from our supplier that we upload into our application. The layout of the information didn't ever change so we used array keys to find/save the data ie. `$first_name = $data[1];`

Recently our supplier has started to modify the order of the columns and I am making modifications to verify if the required headers exist before our system uploads the data from the CSV file.

```
// get headers from csv file
$header = fgetcsv($handle);
// create test aray of required headers
$validate_header = ["FamName", "FirstName", "StaffNo", "HomeGroup", "PayLevel", "Gender", "Status"]; 

foreach($validate_header as $v){
   if (!in_array($v, $header)) {
       // error header not found
       // return user to upload form with error
   } 
}   
// headers all found
```

The problem we have is that the first value in the $header array `($header[0])`, is failing verification.

if we dump the variable its failing on its always the first value [0], in the array. We can change it to anything and it will always fail.

```
$v = "FamName"

$header = array:6 [▼
  0 => "FamName"
  1 => "FirstName"
  2 => "StaffNo"
  3 => "PayLevel"
  4 => "Gender"
  5 => "Status"
]
```

If someone could point me to the cause I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Obviously some unprintable characters in the file, BOM I presume

Comment: That's indeed probably the [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: Check if BOM: `var_dump(mb_strlen($header[0]))`

Comment: how about the other values in the order, did u test it with other values? Also, try printing the head values to check for any some special characters coming along? Also, u can use regex to mitigate this risk!!

Comment: I should mention that every other header field in the file validates just array key 0, but will do some reading on BOM now thank you

Comment: `var_dump(mb_strlen($header[0]))` is 8 should be 7, thank you very much!